# Mezzanine/Django 1.10 migrations: Database tables does not much with migrations

Tags: django, migration, models, mezzanine, makemigrations

I am using Mezzanine (Django 1.10) so I can't see a "`db.sqlite3`"

I searched similar questions as mine and most of the solutions provided were not effective.

I created a new model and later decided to add a new field. I did "python manage.py makemigrations ", and when I looked at my migrations folder, it's there; the new field exists. Now, when I ran the app and looked into admin, it gave me error where it said "No such column exists". Therefore, I think, my database is not synced with the migrations I have.

This is what I did:
1. deleted everything in the migration folder and recreated the "**init**.py".

1.1 ran "`python manage.py makemigrations <app_name>`"

1.2 ran "`python manage.py migrate <app_name>`"

1.3 ran "`python manage.py runserver`"

I can actually just rename my model into a different name with the same fields, however, sometimes Django would give error such as "no such table exist". It would also be quiet tedious to do because if I rename my model, I have to rename it in every file where I have imported the model such as in admin.py, forms.py, views.py, etc.

I heard about South, but its not applicable to Django 1.10.

Please Help. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I just solved this problem. Since I am using Mezzanine then the name of the database is not the same. Look for the file `dev.db` which would be located at the same folder of your `manage.py`. Then, delete it. Then, run `python manage.py makemigrations` and `python manage.py migrate` again. Then (I hope) it would work.